# Django Security issue

Tags: django

So I have just completed my site, it is a basic social network. Each user has a profile and can edit their profile. However if a logged in user switches the user id in the edit url they can edit another users profile.

So if I am logged in as user 1 I can edit my profile here:

```
/user/1/edit
```

However, if logged in as user 1 and I go to user 2's edit profile url here:

```
/user/2/edit
```

I can also edit their profile... How do I stop that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare request.user.id with id in URL args if they are not same return 403 FORBIDDEN ( HttpResponseForbidden() )

You don't even need to have URL formed like following for edit, it could be just `/user/edit` as you can always retrieve current logged in user in your view by using `request.user`. I would recommend you going with the following solution and not consuming user id through URL where scope is limited to current user

Comment: Is it better to do that or in the templates have an if statement that says if its not the correct user don't display anything?

Comment: Templates should be as much as possible cut from logic parts, following should be at the top of your view if you want still go with the approach you stated which I highly discourage.

Comment: Ok so how do I implement the request.user so that it displays the form for them? I understand the concept but I'm a little lost on the code used to implement this